# Non-Blocking IO in java with logic

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I am creating a server that will handle >1000 connections. I decided to go with non-blocking IO in my server. I found some code on the internet, which is basically an echo server. I think everything is fine, but I don't understand a few of the concepts in the server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.*;

public class EchoServer {
     private InetAddress addr;
     private int port;
     private Selector selector;
     private Map<SocketChannel,List<byte[]>> dataMap;

public EchoServer(InetAddress addr, int port) throws IOException {
    this.addr = addr;
    this.port = port;
    dataMap = new HashMap<SocketChannel,List<byte[]>>();
    startServer();
}

private void startServer() throws IOException {
    // create selector and channel
    this.selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    // bind to port
    InetSocketAddress listenAddr = new InetSocketAddress(this.addr, this.port);
    serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddr);
    serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    log("Echo server ready. Ctrl-C to stop.");

    // processing
    while (true) {
        // wait for events
        this.selector.select();

        // wakeup to work on selected keys
        Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();

            // this is necessary to prevent the same key from coming up 
            // again the next time around.
            keys.remove();

            if (! key.isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                this.accept(key);
            }
            else if (key.isReadable()) {
                this.read(key);
            }
            else if (key.isWritable()) {
                this.write(key);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
    channel.configureBlocking(false);

    // write welcome message
    channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("Welcome, this is the echo server\r\n".getBytes("US-     ASCII")));

    Socket socket = channel.socket();
    SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    log("Connected to: " + remoteAddr);

    // register channel with selector for further IO
    dataMap.put(channel, new ArrayList<byte[]>());
    channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}

private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
    int numRead = -1;
    try {
        numRead = channel.read(buffer);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (numRead == -1) {
        this.dataMap.remove(channel);
        Socket socket = channel.socket();
        SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
        log("Connection closed by client: " + remoteAddr);
        channel.close();
        key.cancel();
        return;
    }

    byte[] data = new byte[numRead];
    System.arraycopy(buffer.array(), 0, data, 0, numRead);
    log("Got: " + new String(data, "US-ASCII"));

    // write back to client
    doEcho(key, data);
}

private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    List<byte[]> pendingData = this.dataMap.get(channel);
    Iterator<byte[]> items = pendingData.iterator();
    while (items.hasNext()) {
        byte[] item = items.next();
        items.remove();
        channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(item));
    }
    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}

private void doEcho(SelectionKey key, byte[] data) {
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    List<byte[]> pendingData = this.dataMap.get(channel);
    pendingData.add(data);
    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
}

private static void log(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         new EchoServer(null, 8989);
    }
}
```

So For this code, I have a few questions. One, if I read 10 bytes, but I don't want to do anything until I read 100 bytes, how would I implement that? Also, say I only want to write when a counter reaches a certain number, how would I implement that non-blocking? The thing about this code is, is that it will echo no matter how big the bytebuffer is. How do I change that so it would only echo when it has 100 bytes? How can I write only if a counter is a certain size? Thanks!

Would putting an if(numRead < 100) {do rest} else {return} in the read method work for the first problem?
Also, would putting an if(counter > 100) {do rest} else{return} in the write method work for the second?

Answer (score 0):

You have to code that part, basically you need to keep track of bytes read, keep adding bytes read to temporary buffer and once you reached your required limit, you can pass that buffer to your worker thread.

I'll recommend you to use [netty](http://netty.io/) it provides all the things which you are looking for out of the box.
Look at [this link](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Did channel with non blocking mode return -1 while reading?? For your question, You can set the bytebuffer limit:-

For example:-

```
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
buff.clear();

buff.limit(your_limit);//is this what you want??

while(buff.remaining>0&&channel.read(buff)); // if will reach till your limit only.

System.out.println(new String(buff.array()));
```

hope this help